# Flutter http get request : screen stuck

Tags: flutter, http

I am using an API to get all products that are associated with a user. However, the screen is stuck with the CircularProgressIndicator. I have checked and the response status code is indeed 200, therefore the issue has to be on my end. Kindly help me figure out where i am going wrong.

Code for function getting the data:

```
Future<GetItemsResponseModel> _getItems() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("API_URL"), headers: {
      "authtype": "custom",
      "x-access-token": token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    });
    // print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final String responseString = response.body;
      return getItemsResponseModelFromJson(responseString);
    } else {
      // Error handling code
    }
  }
```

Code for the FutureBuilder :

```
Container(
                    height: 500,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                      future: _getItems(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return GridView.custom(
                            gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
                              crossAxisCount: 4,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                              repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
                              pattern: [
                                QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
                                QuiltedGridTile(1, 2),
                                QuiltedGridTile(1, 2),
                              ],
                            ),
                            childrenDelegate:
                                SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                              if (index == 0) {
                                return AddItem().BuildAddItemButton(token);
                              } else {
                                return ItemCard();
                              }
                            }, childCount: 12),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }
                      },
                    ))
```

For now, i haven't assigned any UI components to use snapshot.data. As i said before the screen is stuck on the progressIndicator and the data is being fetched correctly. How do i resolve this ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Make sure that your `getItemsResponseModelFromJson(responseString)` is doing what it's supposed to do. I'm 80% sure that problem is there.

Comment: I dont think it is, i replaced it with `jsonDecode(responseString);` (That was its function anyway) and still the same result

Comment: Just to be sure can you please assign the result of `jsonDecode(responseString);` to a variable before returning it and check if it's actually of type `GetItemsResponseModel` and not `null`?